# ID check, German ID and German passport rejected in Utah

Tags: usa, alcohol, identity-cards, german-citizens, nightlife

My son (age 21 and a half years) and I (63) wanted to visit a bar in Utah near Salt Lake City. The first time my son was rejected because he had "only" the German ID card. O.K., no problem, we returned to our hotel (0.7 miles away, by walking) and brought the German international passport (Reisepass), which we also used on the border to enter the US. However, he was rejected again.
We will avoid visiting the state of Utah in the future.
Does anybody have an idea if this could also happen in a different state?

Comment: Laws vary widely by state. California used to not even accept the [US Passport](https://www.pillsburylaw.com/images/content/2/9/2950.pdf)!

Comment: You have a law which prohibits alcohol for minors. Then you got a company which tells the employees how to avoid breaking that law. Do you expect a barkeeper to recognize 180+ passports worldwide? A border official might, or he might call a supervisor who can help. A barkeeper could either be ordered to play it safe or to take risks (risks for the company, which might lose the license). Guess which one ...

Comment: Oh, well, the INTERNATIONAL PASSPORT is an agreed document which is reqired for entry into the US. It is accepted there and the INTERNATIONAL PASSPORTS look similar in every country (At least UK, US, France, Austria, Germany, Swizzerland...). So why should a barkeeper not recognize it and find the date of birth?

Comment: And, by the way, if they don't even accept the US Passport in CA then this may be the end of all nightlive in the US...?

Comment: @trebla No. If you read the link, the US Passport, like most passports, does not have a physical description: traits like hair color, height, weight, etc. The law in California was written to require such a description, which is found on driver's licenses/state ID cards. Federal immigration laws do not have bearing on a state's rights to make their own alcohol laws, which is actually given to the states explicitly by the 21st Amendment to the Constitution.

Comment: "if they don't even accept the US Passport in CA then this may be the end of all nightlive in the US": considering the small percentage of US residents who have a US passport, probably not.

Comment: Yes, this happened in upstate NY. My two friends' European ID cards were refused at a bar and they were told full passports were required.

Comment: I've lived in Utah and always used my British passports in bars and shops when asked for ID. In fact it was never rejected anywhere in the USA. Most people in Utah have there driving licence scanned(barcode). The bars usually had to write down my name and passport number instead of scanning something when I showed my passport. Maybe the bar person did not know what to do because he couldn't scan your passport, strange as some people will use a US passport and Salt Lake is very international.

Comment: It's Utah. They don't even like to admit that alcohol exists, let alone sell it to anyone.

Comment: Well, let your money speak. It is clear that you visited that place three times… the first, the last and the only…

Answer (score 3):

Varies from bar to bar; the ones I've been to in New York and LA never had any issue with my Swedish equivalent of your Personalausweis, but I've read that many places won't even accept driving licences not issued in their state. Effectively meaning many places are only open to local residents in practice.

Comment: Ok, this is then Xenophobia...

Comment: @trebla Not really. What I mean is that a Texan bar may not accept a driving licence from Arizona, for example

Comment: @trebla No, it's a rational business decision: the consequences of getting busted serving minors are huge in the US.

Comment: It's not just a business decision... in most states, [including Utah](https://le.utah.gov/xcode/Title32B/Chapter4/32B-4-S403.html?v=C32B-4-S403_1800010118000101), the penalty for somebody serving or selling alcohol to a minor is the same as giving, and is a criminal misdemeanor. In Utah, this is up to 6 months in jail, a $1,000 fine, and of course a permanent criminal history. Therefore it is a personal decision by the server whether they want to accept your ID or not.

Comment: I've used my Virginia driver's license to obtain alcohol in Maryland, New Jersey, Georgia, and DC, and never had anyone balk.

Comment: @user71659 yes, consider this from the perspective of the server, who probably is fairly young and at the beginning of their career. A criminal conviction would be *devastating*, especially a conviction for an offense that (ostensibly) involves endangering young people. I wouldn't be surprised if some states now consider this to be a barrier crime for working with children or vulnerable people, and also forget about ever being a cop or schoolteacher with such a conviction in our political climate.

Comment: Also, Utah alcohol laws have historically always been wonky due to the overwhelming influence of the LDS religion, which is strongly anti-alcohol.

Comment: The bar was erring on the side of caution because the penalties are so severe and he probably does not know that Reisepass means passport. Losing one customer is better than risking his alcohol vendor's license. Even if he sees 02.09.1997 on it, he might not know how dates are written in Europe. If he looked at that and asked when your birthday was, he would assume it was a fake story if you responded "September 2, 1997" which we write as 09/02/1997.

Comment: I had a high school friend who used a French student ID to buy a case of beer when he was 17. Kids have tried this scam with a variety of foreign IDs.

Comment: @BruceDimon the German passport is in German, French, and English, with a key that identifies certain features in every official EU language. It is fairly straightforward to confirm that the document is a passport, even for someone who reads only English, though it does require more than a quick glance and an ability to read fine print, unless the passport was issued in 2017 or later, when they added "passport/passeport" to the cover.

Comment: @phoog everything you say is completely fair and reasonable, but I'd argue it does require a degree of cosmopolitanism.  You've always struck me as very well-travelled; is it at all possible you *might* have forgotten what it's like to be parochial?  As I understand it, only a minority of US citizens have passports and the drivers' licence tends to be primary domestic photo ID.  Some poor local chap serving in a Utah bar (!) outside the metropolitan areas might not be so instantly familiar with *any* passports as, say, you are, and might be forgiven for erring on the side of caution.

Comment: @MadHatter someone might be forgiven for *wanting* to err on the side of caution, but refusing to accept a valid passport (a form of identification that is explicitly named in Utah law) without making a reasonable attempt to determine whether it is in fact a passport, may constitute illegal discrimination on the basis of national origin in a public accommodation. Utah has a healthy tourism sector and in fact has a fairly high percentage of people who have lived in other countries for months thanks to the missionary calling in the Mormon church. It's not as isolated as some seem to think.